# subfig and "caption type already set" + "can't use `\relax' after \advance."

Tags: captions, subfloats, subcaption

I just switched to using `\subfig` as per advice here on TeX.SX . Now, the following code:

```
\begin{figure}[th]
    \centering
    \begin{subfloat}{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics{graphics/q4-execution-plan/transformation-1-before}
        \label{subfig:q4-t1-before}
        \caption{before}
    \end{subfloat}
\end{figure}
```

and am getting:

```
Package caption Warning: The caption type was already set to `subfloat'
(caption)                 on input line 135.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.

! You can't use `\relax' after \advance.
<recently read> \c@subsubfloat 

l.135     \begin{subfloat}
                          {0.5\textwidth}
```

I don't quite understand what's going on... do I need to use more packages/some other combination of packages? Set package options? Or am I just using `\subfloat` wrong?

Comment: Your used syntax remains me on `subcaption` package. Try to add it in preamble and test your document again.

Comment: @Zarko: Getting a compatibility error with Springer llncs...

Comment: In future please provide minimal working example -- small complete document with all *necessary* details for reproducing your document --  which can be compiled. See my answer below.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't use `caption` with `llncs`. Do `\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}`, but use the proper syntax with `\subfloat`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your  sintax i code fragment remains me on `subcaption` syntax. For `subfig` package try the following:

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \subfloat[before     \label{subfig:q4-t1-before}]
{\includegraphics{graphics/q4-execution-plan/transformation-1-before}}

\caption{Main caption}
\end{figure}
```